# Selenium Automation to Select a li Menu Item in An ul with Python and Selenium

Tags: python, selenium, selenium-webdriver, css-selectors, selenium-chromedriver

So I am having an overall issue where I am trying to automate the login, menu-item selection, and then pre-populate the fields to initialize a file download. I have been able to auto login, many thanks to the answer provided within another post. However, I have not been successful in trying to navigate to a specific menu item and select that item to take me to a new page. If I go to that page directly, I am logged out and have to log back in. There is a spot called "Custom Reports", this is what I need to click on to take me to another page. If the li objects had IDs it would make this so much easier, however there are no IDs as one could imagine. Here is the source for the Webpage I am trying to automate, follow the link to it that I have stored in github.

https://github.com/Richard-Barrett/ITDataServicesInfra/blob/master/Python/Collegeboard/TSI/tsi_pagesource

I am trying to click on this element

```
                  <li ng-show="core.acl['244']!='N'" ng-class="{active:isLocation('/customReports')}">
                     <a href="#/customReports" translate='reports.CustomReports.title'></a>
                  </li>
```

As you can imagine, I have not been able to do so. 
Here is the code I am using to pull out the information so far. Login Automation works.

```
#!/bin/python
# ===========================================================
# Created By: Richard Barrett
# Organization: DVISD
# DepartmenT: Data Services
# Purpose: Test Score & 3rd Party Website Data Pull Automation
# Date: 01/20/2020
# ===========================================================

import selenium
import os
import unittest
import requests
import time
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.support.select import Select

#Variable Definitions NEED TO MAKE
#find_elements_by_name
#find_elements_by_xpath
#find_elements_by_link_text
#find_elements_by_partial_link_text
#find_elements_by_tag_name
#find_elements_by_class_name
#find_elements_by_css_selector


#URL Variables
login_url = 'https://www.accuplacer.org/'
redirect_url = 'https://www.accuplacer.org/api/home.html#/'
reports_scheduler_url = 'https://www.accuplacer.org/api/home.html#/reportScheduler'
custom_reports_url = 'https://www.accuplacer.org/api/home.html#/customReports'

#WebDriver Path
browser = webdriver.Chrome("C:\Program Files (x86)\Google\Chrome\chromedriver.exe")

#Parent URL
browser.get("https://www.accuplacer.org")

# Authentication
# Credentials NEEDS TO BE ENCRYPTED AND NOT BAKED INTO THE SCRIPT NEEDS UNIT TEST
username = browser.find_element_by_id("login")
password = browser.find_element_by_id("password")
username.send_keys("##############")
password.send_keys("##############")
#browser.send_keys(Keys.ENTER)
#browser.send_keys(Keys.RETURN)

# Work on Notifications Window Clause
# Need a step for when notifications appear to click "Submit" option
# <button type="button" ng-show="updateWhatsNewFlag == 'failure'" translate="submit" class="btn btn-sm btn-success ng-scope" ng-click="updateShowWhatsNewFlag()" style="">Submit</button>

# Need a step to close if the notification popup window is present
# <button type="button" class="btn btn-default ng-scope" data-dismiss="modal" ng-click="clearMessages()" translate="common.btn.close">Close</button>

# Authentication submit.click()
#browser.find_element_by_css_selector('.btn.btn-lg.btn-primary').click()
element = WebDriverWait(browser, 20).until(
        EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.CSS_SELECTOR, ".btn.btn-lg.btn-primary.pull-left")))
element.click();

#Navigate to CustomReports XPATH=//*[@id="leftNav"]/ul/li[11]/ul/li[9]/a
#browser.find_element_by_xpath('//*[@id="leftNav"]/ul/li[11]').click()


# Make the report by selecting objects
#obj_report = Select(browser.find_element_by_name("Reports"))
element = WebDriverWait(browser, 20).until(
        EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.CSS_XPATH, "*[@id="leftNav"]/ul/li[11]/ul/li[9]/a")))
element.click();
```

Everytime I try to us the xpath it doesn't give me anything and basically says it doesn't exist.

Comment: I recently restructured the repository for the page source and selenium recording: https://github.com/Richard-Barrett/ITDataServicesInfra/blob/master/Python/Selenium/Workflows/SeIDE_TSI_WORKFLOW

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The desired element is an [Angular](https://angular.io/) element so to locate and `click()` on the element you need to induce *WebDriverWait* for the `element_to_be_clickable()` and you can use either of the following  [Locator Strategies](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48369043/official-locator-strategies-for-the-webdriver/48376890#48376890):

- Using `CSS_SELECTOR`:

  ```
  WebDriverWait(browser, 20).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.CSS_SELECTOR, "li>a[href$='customReports'][translate*='CustomReports']"))).click()
  ```
- Using `XPATH`:

  ```
  WebDriverWait(browser, 20).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH, "//li/a[contains(@href,'customReports') and contains(@translate, 'CustomReports')]"))).click()
  ```
- **Note** : You have to add the following imports :

  ```
  from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
  from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
  from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
  ```

Comment: Added those in ```DevTools listening on ws://127.0.0.1:60753/devtools/browser/8cb1948b-10e1-46bd-ad25-e4fcf8ff49e6
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File ".\collegboard_tsi_export.py", line 69, in <module>
    custom_report = WebDriverWait(browser, 20).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH, "//li[contains(@ng-class, 'customReports')]/a[contains(@href,'customReports')]")))
  File "C:\Python38\lib\site-packages\selenium\webdriver\support\wait.py", line 80, in until
    raise TimeoutException(message, screen, stacktrace)
selenium.common.exceptions.TimeoutException: Message:```

Comment: @R.Barrett Checkout the updated answer and let me know the status.

Comment: Looking into it.

Comment: I had already tried it with the naming convention browser instead of the driver. Just tried it still no luck. I did record a Selenium Recording Test and saved the output here https://github.com/Richard-Barrett/ITDataServicesInfra/blob/master/Python/Selenium/TSI_CustomReport_Element_Identification

Comment: @R.Barrett There was a change in the xpath and cssSelector as well, let me know the status.

Comment: I was not able to to use either command, no selection is occurring.

Comment: I found the solution, I had to use LINK_TEXT ```element = WebDriverWait(browser, 20).until(
        EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.LINK_TEXT, "Reports")))
element.click();

element = WebDriverWait(browser, 20).until(
                EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.LINK_TEXT, "Custom Reports")))
element.click();```

Answer (score 0):

Please try below code using `xpath` with  webdriver `explicit wait`.

```
element = WebDriverWait(browser, 20).until(
EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH, "//a[contains(@href, '/customReports')]")))
element.click();
```

you need below import

```
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
```

**OR**

**Not recommended but a working solution in most cases (try to click with Java script but without wait as it can be fail on wait )**

```
element=browser.find_element(By.XPATH, "//a[contains(@href, '/customReports')]")
browser.execute_script("arguments[0].click();", element)
```

Comment: I tried the following but we are using 3 positional arguments instead of 2 ```PS C:\Users\richard.barrett\Git\ITDataServicesInfra\Python\Collegeboard\TSI> python .\collegboard_tsi_export.py

DevTools listening on ws://127.0.0.1:59923/devtools/browser/49c4c813-8147-4d85-adae-41b085059367
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File ".\collegboard_tsi_export.py", line 64, in <module>
    EC.element_to_be_clickable(By.XPATH,"//a[contains(@href, '/customReports')"))
TypeError: __init__() takes 2 positional arguments but 3 were given```

Comment: @R.Barrett Can you try last solution with Java script

Comment: @R.Barrett, As I am typing from mobile so I missed the 1 ()  in that  line. Now you can try it.

Comment: I found the solution ```element = WebDriverWait(browser, 20).until(
        EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.LINK_TEXT, "Reports")))
element.click();

element = WebDriverWait(browser, 20).until(
                EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.LINK_TEXT, "Custom Reports")))
element.click();```

Comment: I had to use LINK_TEXT

Comment: Well. I write xpath based on Linktext/Href. Enjoy

Comment: `Linktext` which resembles the `innerText` and `href` both are HTML attributes but are quite different.

Comment: You are right. But InnerText don’t play any vital role it is just alias for any <a> but If any <a> don’t have href you can’t call it LinkText. HREF is only attribute who make any anchor LinkText.

Comment: @Muzzamil Incorrect, DOM events can even do the job.

Comment: @DebanjanB  Right,  I think you are talking about onClick() event but that part is belong to JS. Don’t take it as arguments, I am seeing in healthy discussion can help to learn new thing.

Answer (score 0):

So I ended up finding the solution. The solution is that I had to first navigate to reports and then move on the child item of custom reports. I used Link_Text instead.

```
element = WebDriverWait(browser, 20).until(
        EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.LINK_TEXT, "Reports")))
element.click();

element = WebDriverWait(browser, 20).until(
                EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.LINK_TEXT, "Custom Reports")))
element.click();
```

I appreciate all of the help from you guys @DebanjB and @Muzzamil, I doubt without their guidance I would not have been able to find out how to do this! Much appreciated you two.